# Slim background color line after the border

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I'm making a `custom UIView`. I have a full `red circle` with `white border` as a part of my `view`.

I hope it's visible but I'm getting a very slim line with the color of the backgroundColor around the border.

How can I get rid of this line?

Thanks!

[image: red circle]

my Code:

```
class QTBadgedView: UIView {

fileprivate lazy var badgeView: UIView = {
    let badge = UIView()
    badge.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    badge.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    badge.layer.borderWidth = 2
    return badge
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initialize()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialize()
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    badgeView.layer.cornerRadius = badgeView.frame.width/2
}
}

extension QTBadgedView {

public var badgeColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        return badgeView.backgroundColor
    }
    set(newColor) {
        badgeView.backgroundColor = newColor
    }
}
}

extension QTBadgedView {
fileprivate func initialize() {

    addSubview(iconImageView)
    addSubview(badgeView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        iconImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
        iconImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
        iconImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor),
        iconImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),

        badgeView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        badgeView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        badgeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.topAnchor),
        badgeView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.trailingAnchor),

        ])
}
}
```